# Matlab: Replace zeros with last non-zero index

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a matrix Cr of size 352x240 uint_8.
[image: Output matrix]

How can I replace zeros with last non-zero index?
For example, output should be like this:

```
141 141 141 142 ...
141 141 141 142 ...
141 141 141 142 ...
141 141 141 142 ...
149 148 150 150 ...
 .   .   .   .  ...
 .   .   .   .  ...
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use range indexing and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
result = repelem(Cr(1:4:end, :), 4, 1);
```

EDIT
In general case this method can be used:

```
f = find(Cr);
result = reshape(repelem(Cr(f), diff([f;numel(Cr)+1])), size(Cr));
```

Answer (score 7):

This works in the **general case** when the occurrence of zeros and nonzeros is not necessarily periodic or consistent across columns. It assumes that the first row doesn't contain zeros (otherwise the problem is undefined):

```
result = Cr(cummax((Cr~=0).*(1:size(Cr,1)).', 1) + (0:size(Cr,1):numel(Cr)-1));
```

To understand how it works, see:

- [Singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/)
- [Linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/)
- [`cummax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html).

Example:

```
>> Cr = [141 141 141; 0 0 0; 0 0 145; 147 0 0; 149 148 0; 0 0 0]
Cr =
   141   141   141
     0     0     0
     0     0   145
   147     0     0
   149   148     0
     0     0     0

>> result = Cr(cummax((Cr~=0).*(1:size(Cr,1)).', 1) + (0:size(Cr,1):numel(Cr)-1))
result =
   141   141   141
   141   141   141
   141   141   145
   147   141   145
   149   148   145
   149   148   145
```

Answer (score 2):

If we think like a matrix array in C++, this should work:

```
matrix[n][m]=matrix[n-((n-1)%4)][m]
```

All the numbers which is not 0 are in index (1,5,9,13...).
So it is n=1(mod4). Simple math would work for this.